# Python UDP socket, doesn't receive response on Windows

Tags: python, windows, sockets, udp

I've been running a UDP client-server communication with Python with the following code.

On the server side the code is as follows:

```
import socket
import time

# Create a UDP socket
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to a specific IP address and port
server_address = ('192.168.100.2', 9910)
server_socket.bind(server_address)

print('Server is up and running!')

while True:
    # Receive data from the client
    data, client_address = server_socket.recvfrom(1024)
    
    # Process the received data
    message = data.decode()
    print('Received message from client:', message)
    time.sleep(240)
    # Send a response back to the client
    response = 'OK'
    server_socket.sendto(response.encode(), client_address)
    print(f"Sent response: {response} to {client_address}")
```

You can see that there is a `time.sleep(240)` in the code, because the code its simulating a use case where the server recieves UDP command, than performs some work that takes around few minutes and then sends "OK" back to the client.

On the client side I have two implementations.
The first one is simply sending a command and recieving response:

```
import socket

# Create a UDP socket
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.settimeout(300)
# Server address
server_address = ('192.168.100.2', 9910)

# Send data to the server
message = 'Hello from the client!'
client_socket.sendto(message.encode(), server_address)

# Receive response from the server
response, _ = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)

# Process the received response
response_message = response.decode()
print('Received response from server:', response_message)

# Close the socket
client_socket.close()
```

You can see that I have a `client_socket.settimeout(300)`, because the server takes 240 seconds to send back a response.

The issues is as follows: When I run the client code on Linux, everything is working fine. The server returns an "OK" message after 240 seconds and the client recieves it. However, when I run the client code on Windows, the method `response, _ = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)` doesn't pick up the UDP  response from the server and it timeouts after 300 seconds.

I've tried an alternative approach for the client side - with a while loop:

```
        command_to_be_send = f"flashIntel"

        client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        client_socket .settimeout(20)
        _log.info(f"Sending command: [{command_to_be_send}] to the device via UDP")
        client_socket .sendto(command_to_be_send.encode(), ("192.168.100.2", 9910))

        while(True):
            response = None
            try:
                response, addr = client_socket.recvfrom(1024)
            except Exception as e:
                _log.info(e)
                pass
            if response:
                break

        response_text = response.decode().strip()
        _log.info(f"Received response: [{response_text}] from [{addr}]")

        client_socket.close()
```

This implementaion also works on Linux, but not on Windows. I am sniffing with WireShark and I can clearly see the packet coming back, but for some reason the code doesn't register it.

Comment: Works for me on Windows.   Are you running the client and server on the same machine or two different machines?  The server would have to be the 192.168.100.2 machine.  Firewall?

Comment: @MarkTolonen The issue was Windows firewall rules that were closing the socket.